# Returning results of groupBy() on an array of objects from a map() in lodash results in [object]

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to do two groupBy on an array of objects (**essentially I am trying to chain two groupBy)**

```
let lodash = require('lodash');
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'dog' },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'dog' },
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'cat' },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'goldfish' }
];

var groupByAge = lodash.groupBy(characters, 'age');

//console.log(groupByAge);

var groupByAgeAndPet = lodash.map(groupByAge, function(value){
  return lodash.groupBy(value, 'pet');

});

console.log(groupByAgeAndPet);
```

The output, however, is:

> [ { dog: [ [Object] ], goldfish: [ [Object] ] },   { dog: [ [Object]
>   ], cat: [ [Object] ] } ]

If I do a console.log() within the map, I will get the result I want.

What should I be using instead of `lodash.map()` or do I need to apply some processing before returning from map.

repl.it link to the code: https://repl.it/@Kun_XinXin/OptimalUnkemptTrapezoids

Here's the expected return:

```
{
   35: { dog: [ { name: 'barney', age: 42, pet: 'dog' } ],
  cat: [ { name: 'barney', age: 42, pet: 'cat' } ] },
   42:{ dog: [ { name: 'fred', age: 35, pet: 'dog' } ],
  goldfish: [ { name: 'fred', age: 35, pet: 'goldfish' } ] }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong? please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: do you want to sort by pet

Comment: you're returning groupBy(value, 'pet') in a map that returns an array you are passing in value witch is a object so its returning an array with an object in what are you trying to do so we can help

Comment: Added expected return

Answer (score 0):

With native javascript and array `reduce` function the same output can be achieved.Create a function and pass a parameter by which the objects will be grouped. For example in the below function you can pass `name`,`age`,`pet` so the object will be grouped by this key name.

```js
var characters = [{
    'name': 'barney',
    'age': 42,
    'pet': 'dog'
  },
  {
    'name': 'fred',
    'age': 35,
    'pet': 'dog'
  },
  {
    'name': 'barney',
    'age': 42,
    'pet': 'cat'
  },
  {
    'name': 'fred',
    'age': 35,
    'pet': 'goldfish'
  }
];



// creating a function which accepts an parameter which will be used to
// group the objects
function groupBy(keyName) {
  return characters.reduce(function(acc, curr, currIndex) {
    // checking if the object have any key by which the object will be grouped
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(curr[keyName])) {
      // if not create a key 
      acc[curr[keyName]] = [];
      acc[curr[keyName]].push(curr)
    }
    // else just push the value
    acc[curr[keyName]].push(curr);
    return acc;

  }, {})
}
 // replace pet with name or age to group result by that key
console.log(groupBy('pet'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone come across this while using `console.log` to debug such cases, it is actually working; it's just that somehow the object contain inside is shortened to `[object]`

If you access the object directly using console.log, it does work.

```
let lodash = require('lodash');
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'dog' },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'dog' },
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 42,  'pet': 'cat' },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 35,  'pet': 'goldfish' }
];

var groupByAge = lodash.groupBy(characters, 'age');

//console.log(groupByAge);

var groupByAgeAndPet = lodash.mapValues(groupByAge, function(value){
  return lodash.groupBy(value, 'pet');

});

// this will display the actual object instead of the string 
console.log(groupByAgeAndPet[35]);
```